# Was macht es so schwierig die deutsche Sprache zu lernen? / Why is German so hard to learn?

Tags: learning

Als Muttersprachler fällt mir die deutsche Sprache natürlich vergleichsweise leicht. Von Lernenden höre ich allerdings immer wieder, dass besonders Deutsch eine schwer zu erlernende Sprache ist. Was genau sind die Gründe dafür?

---

It has been said that German is a particularly difficult language to learn. As a native speaker, I find it hard to understand the difficulties learners have with that language. What are the main reasons for these difficulties?

Comment: Ich kenne einige Leute, die Deutsch als Fremdsprache gelernt haben, und zwei Dinge, mit denen sie immer Probleme hatten, sind die Geschlechter der Wörter (drei Geschlechter, ohne dass man den Wörtern ansehen kann, welchem Geschlecht sie angehören, sind viel Ballast beim Lernen) und die unregelmäßigen Flexionen vieler Verben und Nomen (mit denen tatsächlich ja viele Muttersprachler nicht klarkommen: ich schwamm/ich schwomm etc.).

Comment: @cemper93: schreib' das ruhig als Antwort, wenn Du magst :-)

Comment: @cemper93 Wir müssen einfach mit der nächsten Reform das "den" als optionalen Ersatz für alle drei Artikel einführen. Hat sich in der Umgangssprache ja bereits verbreitet ("kommt auf den Pommes noch was drauf?") ;-)

Comment: Ich vermisse sowohl in der Frage, als auch in allen Antworten etwas sehr wichtiges, nämlich für wen es leicht oder schwer ist Deutsch zu lernen. Dänen werden vermutlich leichter Deutsch lernen als z.B. Japanisch. Für einen Koreaner ist es vermutlich umgekehrt. Hier wird aber durch die Bank so getan, als wäre die Muttersprache aller Menschen, die Deutsch als Fremdsprache lernen wollen, Englisch. Das ist FALSCH! Wer z.B. in Wien Deutsch als Fremdsprache lernt, hat fast immer Türkisch, oder eine slawische oder arabische Sprache als  Muttersprache.

Comment: Schwierig sind die Flexionsformen und die Wortstelling.

Comment: Ist doch gar nicht schwer... in Deutschland lernen sogar Babys deutsch... ;-P

Answer (score 16):

Mal ein paar objektive Fakten:

> The Foreign Service Institute (FSI) of the US Department of State has compiled approximate learning expectations for a number of languages based on the length of time it takes to achieve Speaking 3: General Professional Proficiency in Speaking (S3) and Reading 3: General Professional Proficiency in Reading (R3). The list is limited to languages taught at the Foreign Service Institute, minus languages which don't have their own Wikibook. Note that this only states the views of The Foreign Service Institute (FSI) of the US Department of State, and many language learners and experts would disagree with the ranking. It must also be kept in mind that students at FSI are almost 40 years old, are native speakers of English and have a good aptitude for formal language study, plus knowledge of several other foreign languages. They study in small classes of no more than six. Their schedule calls for 25 hours of class per week with three or four hours per day of directed self-study.

[Tabelle](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Wikibooks%3aLanguage_Learning_Difficulty_for_English_Speakers)

---

[Grammatik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difficulty_of_learning_languages):

> A study on speech comprehension by German immigrants to the USA and American immigrants to Germany found that native English speakers learning German as adults had a disadvantage on certain grammatical tasks, while they had an advantage in lexical tasks compared to their native German-speaking counterparts learning English.

---

[grössere Online-Abstimmung](http://www.lexiophiles.com/featured-articles/results-of-the-hardest-languages-to-learn-poll):

> The hardest languages to learn overall:
>
> 1. Mandarin
> 2. Polish
> 3. Arabic
> 4. Hungarian
> 5. Japanese
> 6. English
> 7. Finnish
> 8. Basque
> 9. Lithuanian
> 10. Icelandic
>
> The hardest languages to learn to pronounce correctly:
>
> 1. Mandarin
> 2. Polish
> 3. French
> 4. Arabic
> 5. English
> 6. Japanese
> 7. Hindi
> 8. Korean
> 9. Hungarian
> 10. Basque
>
> The hardest languages to learn to write correctly:
>
> 1. Mandarin
> 2. Japanese
> 3. Arabic
> 4. Korean
> 5. Polish
> 6. Hindi
> 7. Greek
> 8. English
> 9. French
> 10. Hungarian

---

[Kenntnisse aus der Sprachdidaktik:](http://www.deutschservice.de/felix/daf/gesprkom.html#4x3x1)

> Komplizierte Satzgefüge mit zahlreichen Nebensätzen sind eindeutig ein
>   Ausdrucksmittel der Schriftsprache, das im mündlichen Sprachgebrauch
>   einfach nicht praktikabel ist, weil solch umfängliche Konstruktionen
>   bei der spontanen Sprachproduktion den Rahmen der
>   Gedächtnisleistungsfähigkeit sprengen würden. Das hat auch Grundmann
>   (1975: 407) erkannt, der es als "wirklichkeitsfremd" kritisiert, wenn
>   von muttersprachlich deutschen Schülern erwartet wird, dass sie auch
>   beim Sprechen zur Bildung komplizierter Satzgefüge in der Lage sein
>   sollten. Solches zu verlangen, hält er für "abwegig".
>
> Demgegenüber steht die bereits in Kapitel 3. angeführte Beobachtung
>   von Haag (1985: 54), dass **zahlreiche nicht-muttersprachliche
>   Deutschlernende dazu neigen, auch in mündlicher Rede relativ komplexe
>   Satzgebilde produzieren zu wollen, weil die Grammatik, die sie im
>   DaF-Unterricht vermittelt bekommen haben, die schriftsprachliche war
>   und sie nicht mit Strategien vertraut gemacht worden sind, wie sie
>   ihre Gedanken beim Sprechen einfacher in Sätze fassen können.**
>
> Da es aber schlechterdings unmöglich ist, so zu sprechen, wie man
>   schreiben würde, sollte im Rahmen des Trainings der Sprechfertigkeit
>   im DaF-Unterricht unbedingt eingeübt werden, **wie Sinnzusammenhänge,
>   die schriftlich durch ineinander verwobene Haupt- und Nebensätze
>   ausgedrückt werden können, auch durch Aneinanderreihung mehrerer
>   separater Hauptsätze wiedergegeben werden können.** Das bedeutet
>   insbesondere, dass die Lernenden Redemittel an die Hand bekommen
>   müssen, mittels derer die **Verbindung von Hauptsätzen zu realisieren
>   ist, so wie sie schließlich auch die Konjunktionen der Nebensätze
>   kennen lernen.**[...]
>
> **Aus dieser Arbeit sollte deutlich hervorgegangen sein, wie sehr sich
>   die gesprochene Sprache auch in grammatischer Hinsicht von der
>   geschriebenen unterscheidet. Zahlreiche Strukturen, die sich in
>   mündlichen Äußerungen mit schöner Regelmäßigkeit finden, weichen von
>   dem ab, was in der Schriftsprache als grammatikalisch akzeptabel
>   erachtet wird. Das bedeutet, dass keine Rede von der Existenz eines
>   einzigen, universellen grammatischen Systems der deutschen Sprache
>   sein kann, welches für schriftlichen sowie mündlichen Sprachgebrauch
>   gleichermaßen absolute Autorität für sich in Anspruch nehmen könnte.
>   Vielmehr weist die gesprochene Sprache auch diverse eigene
>   Gesetzmäßigkeiten auf, die durchaus nicht nur als chaotische, planlose
>   Abweichungen von der schriftsprachlichen Grammatik zu sehen sind,
>   sondern großenteils selbst wiederum als ein System grammatischer
>   Regularitäten formuliert werden könnten.**

---

andere interessante Links:

[**Schwierigkeiten der dt. Sprache**](http://how-to-learn-any-language.com/e/languages/german/index.html#difficulties)
[Vergleich vieler Sprachen I](http://how-to-learn-any-language.com/e/languages/index.html) + [II](http://www.micheloud.com/FXM/la/LA/index.htm)
[The Awful German Language by Mark Twain](http://how-to-learn-any-language.com/e/languages/german/the-awful-german-language.html)

Comment: would give an additional +1 for the Links

Comment: Polish in the top three makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @c.p. +1. Especially inbetween Korean and Hindi in the writing-correctly table.

Comment: The list-results of the poll are more influenced by popularity than real difficulty I suspect. Japanese is hard to pronounce? It has very few phonemes and they are pretty easy to learn. While Mandarin is hard to write, it has easy to learn grammar (a category not covered by the poll). I wouldn't put to much credibility into this list.

Answer (score 13):

**Besonders schwer im Vergleich zu welcher Sprache, und für welche Muttersprache des/der Lernenden?**

Ein paar Aspekte, warum ich Deutsch nicht gerade für eine besonders schwer erlernbare Sprache halte:

- Da die deutschen Vokabeln z. B. im Vergleich zu Englisch durchschnittlich länger sind, verursachen Schreib-/Sprechfehler seltener kritische Bedeutungsveränderungen und somit weniger Kommunikationsprobleme.
- Im Deutschen gibt es relativ verlässliche Regeln für die Aussprache, da ist z. B. Englisch wesentlich schwieriger und weniger konsistent. Ganz zu schweigen von z. B. Chinesisch, wo die Verbindung zwischen Schrift und Sprache schlicht nicht existiert, und ein Wort je nach Aussprache völlig unterschiedliche Bedeutungen haben kann. Im Deutschen jedoch kann man in den meisten Fällen ein unbekanntes Wort korrekt schreiben, wenn man es zum ersten Mal hört, oder korrekt aussprechen, wenn man es zum ersten Mal liest.
- Nicht gerade ein Alleinstellungsmerkmal in der Welt, aber: Deutsch benutzt ein Alphabet, das wesentlich flexibler ist als ein Schriftzeichensystem und die Erfindung neuer Wörter erlaubt. Sprachen mit Schriftzeichen müssen Wörter mit neuer Bedeutung i. Allg. mit Überladung alter Schriftzeichen einführen, was natürlich in Zeiten der Globalisierung und technischen Fortschritts auf Dauer nicht funktionieren kann. Man muss auch, statt des Alphabets mit 26/30 Buchstaben, viele hundert schön anzusehende, aber hundsgemein schwer zu merkende Schriftzeichen beherrschen, um überhaupt anzufangen, z. B. eine Zeitung zu lesen.
- Wenig kultureller Ballast: Um die Bedeutung eines Wortes vollkommen zu erfassen, ist selten ein starker kultureller Hintergrund nötig – wiederum ist Chinesisch ein krasses Gegenbeispiel, das sehr viele im Wesentlichen unübersetzbare Wörter hat.
- "Schwierig zu lernen" hat auch damit zu tun, welche Möglichkeiten zum Training man hat. Versuch mal, mit einem durchschnittlichen Franzosen ins Gespräch zu kommen – wenn man nicht schon rudimentär Französisch kann, wird’s schwer, da die generelle Unwilligkeit der Franzosen, Fremdsprachen zu lernen, nicht nur ein Vorurteil ist. In Deutschland, behaupte ich jetzt mal, kann ein Großteil der unter 30-Jährigen mindestens eine Fremdsprache (meist Englisch), bzw. gibt es viele Ressourcen im Internet zum formalen Üben wie auch informellen Lesen/Schreiben mit Muttersprachlern.

Insofern ist "schwer zu lernen" relativ. Haben die Lernenden, von denen du das hörst, Vergleichsmöglichkeiten mit anderen Fremdsprachen, oder ist das generell ihre einzige Fremdsprache bisher?

Comment: Wie in meiner Frage ja auch schon durchscheinen sollte: ich selbst halte Deutsch auch nicht für sonderlich schwer zu lernen, bin aber natürlich als Muttersprachler auch immer voreingenommen - deshalb die offen formulierte Frage. Was die Vergleichsmöglichkeiten mit anderen Sprachen angeht: Da kann ich jetzt keine allgemeingültige Aussage treffen. Ich denke, am ehesten wird man es mit anderen westlichen Weltsprachen wie Englisch, Französisch oder Spanisch vergleichen.

Comment: Bezüglich "Wenig kultureller Ballast": mich würd interessieren ob das wirklich stimmt. Viele grundsätzliche Worte benötigen keinen kulturellen Hintegrund, aber für die *vielzahl* der Redewendungen, festen Phrasen und ähnliches gilt das keineswegs: hier ist der kulturelle Hintergrund meiner meinung nach sehr wichtig.

Comment: Mit "kultureller Ballast" meine ich solche Wörter und Redewendungen, die ohne tiefe Kenntniss der Kultur des jeweiligen Landes schlicht nicht ausreichend prägnant und benutzbar zu übersetzen sind, weder wörtlich noch sinngemäß, weil es einfach kein Äquivalent in anderen Sprachen gibt. Quasi solche Worte, für deren Übersetzung man ganze Abhandlungen schreiben könnte bzw. deren Bedeutung den Kern ganzer Philosophien oder Religionen darstellen. Davon gibt es im Deutschen, glaube ich, im Vergleich z.B. zum Chinesischen, relativ wenige Worte.

Comment: Im Deutschen gibt es zum Beispiel mit "Gemütlichkeit" und "Heimat" Worte, die sich nicht 1:1 ins Englische übersetzen lassen. Ich weiß, daß Russisch mit "rodina" etwas für Heimat hat, aber das englische "home" deckt nur einen Teilaspekt ab. Ich nehme an, daß es noch eine Menge anderer solcher Worte gibt.

Answer (score 7):

As a learner, one of the most difficult parts is "word order". Actually, after months I cannot decide where to place *nicht* or *adverbs* in the sentence. English was the first foreign language I started to learn years ago, there's no such a rule about making negative forms of a sentence, or you're free to place adverbs at the beginning , end or in the middle of sentences.

Answer (score 6):

German is definitely not SO hard to learn. There are a couple of things that may influence the subjective perception of how difficult a language is.

First, the less similar a language is to your native one or to the one you already know (especially grammatically and phonetically), the harder it will seem to you. German is definitely easier to learn for someone whose native language is English than for someone whose native language is, say, Chinese or Finnish. And once you've become good at one Germanic language,  the other languages from this group will start to look a lot easier than before.

Second, the more a language deviates from the rules, the more you will need to remember.
For example, irregular grammatical forms or grammatical gender that can be hard to predict make it harder for the learner. In other words, the unpredictability is what adds to the difficulty.

Speaking of German, there are some irregularities but I wouldn't say there are too many of them. German pronunciation is not too difficult, either. In terms of overall difficulty, I would put German somewhere close to English. And I wouldn't put English in the top 10 hardest languages. It belongs more on the list of top 10 easiest languages, in my opinion.

From the point of view of a Russian native speaker (which I am) and considering that I started to learn German after I was pretty good at English, I can note the following difficulties:

- Noun genders are sometimes hard to remember and they cannot be easily predicted. Even though the Russian language has the same notion of genders, I think Russian genders are easier to guess based on the noun's ending.
- Irregular forms of verbs, adjectives etc. are similar to English, so I can't say it's the hardest part for me.
- Noun case diclension is more complicated than in English (where it's practically non-existent) but after Russian noun diclension, it's not the hardest part either.
- Word order is sometimes unusual compared to some other languages, but it is actually quite easy to get used to. Trennbare Verben can drive me crazy sometimes. When you're saying a sentence, you have to allocate additonal memory to store the separable prefix and not forget to put it back at the end.

So my final thought is, German is pretty damn easy. My only compaint is that it's not as widespread as English, so it's harder to maintain what you've learned if you don't live in a German-speaking country, unlike English which is everywhere whether you want it or not.

Comment: I think th efact that English is nearly ubiquitious not only makes it easier to keep training it, it is at the same time one reason why English has evolved to a simpler language (except for the spelling/pronunciation discrepancy) over time: A global community using it as a *lingua franca* does have influence in the long run on the language. By the same reason, "smaller" languages have kept many idiosyncratic pecularities (and yes, mandarin is *in theory* and grammarwise a relatively simple language).

Comment: One thing that you didn't mention was prepositions and particles. I'm still not totally sure about the nebulous relationship between *an*, *um*, *auf*, *zu*, *neben*, and *bei*, and after a while I gave up and just started memorizing on a case-by-case basis: She goes *zu* the dentist; He is *zu* house; the door is *zu*; the rent is *zu* damn high. This homography/polysemy of many German words can drive a man crazy.

Comment: @Mihai You're right. Prepositions are usually difficult in any language. English is no better in this regard, by the way. Memorizing is often the only way to get them right. Sometimes it's not so clear-cut even for German native speakers. An exapmple would be a long-debated question wether there's a (significant) difference between ["sprechen _von_" or "sprechen _über_"](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20315/sprechen-von-vs-sprechen-%C3%BCber).

Answer (score 4):

The basics of languages are just rules: one memorizes words and grammer. Maybe in German there are more grammer rules than in English, for example, and more pieces to the vocabulary that must be memorized, but the rules are consistent, so overall I would say German is likely not **that** hard.

Anyone can memorize with effort, and things that seemed completely insane, might but a few months later seem quite natural (for example German plurals compared to English plurals).

The real difficulty is with words and phrases that are not a 1-to-1 matching with the native language, and aren't a simple memorization (for example English lacks word genders, but there is no mystery in how to use genders once they are memorized).

English and German are quite similar, actually. With straightforward memorization, an English speaker can directly become conversational at a party.

---

The difficult ledge to surmount is sounding intelligent, and not having to dance around and clarify statements. When to use words like "doch" or "mal", for example, when a 1-to-1 translation from the native language doesn't need that "filler". When to use verbs that don't have a clear 1-to-1 relationship, changing how one thinks about prepositions...the scary unknown of bridging that gap into thinking in a foreign language.

It's quite hard to think in another language rather than a 1-to-1 translation, since normally when trying to communicate, even if one has the rules memorized, one speaks without thinking. One must memorize whole phrases 100 times at least---it's a harder, more rote memorization than what I spoke of before. Maybe English is not the right language to explain these thoughts, since it (or I) lack the distinquishing words ;-p

---

If German, compared to the native language, has more cases, and thus requires more distinction where the native language has none, that is quite hard. There are more prepositions, for example. Or the difference between "kennen" and "wissen", or "Zeit" and Mal.

The second hardest thing is listening comprehension, since one's brain is so hard wired to interpret word sounds in one's mother language. Try listening to songs in another language and see if you don't hear phrases from your mother language! When listening, one has so little time to process information. It is overwhelming compared to reading at one's own pace. Furthermore, the information is of much lower quality. I read a linguist who once said that it's amazing we can communicate at all, considering how much context we use to understand spoken words.

[This is just based on my experience compared to learning other languages. For some reason I've found German the most natural of all, and that is really what counts for the individual on whether something is "hard" or not. I definitely feel right now, after a couple years and getting to a point of fluency that still feels like fast 1-to-1 translation, that German is hard, I'm just not sure that it is the fault of German.]

---

@Gigili: (ich konnte keinen Kommentar für dich lassen)

- [Time, Manner, and Place: Ordering Adverbs in German Sentences](http://www.brighthub.com/education/languages/articles/34406.aspx)
- [Where should I put "nicht" ?](http://courseware.nus.edu.sg/e-daf/kimdh/Elementary%20German%20I/Einheit6/position_nicht.htm)

Comment: Thank you so much for the references, they were so helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Es gibt immer wieder Leute, die behaupten, Sprache *X* sei einfach und Sprache *Y* sei schwer zu erlernen. Kurioserweise widersprechen sie sich meistens in der Frage, welche Sprachen einfach sind, während zu vermeintlich schwere Sprachen oft Einigkeit herrscht (solange nicht eine der Diskutanten diese Sprache als *einfach* kategorisiert).

Dabei sehe ich jedoch einige Probleme:

1. Jede noch lebende nicht-künstliche Sprache hat Muttersprachler und jede ausgestorbene nicht-künstliche Sprache hat Muttersprachler gehabt.

   Das klingt zwar irgendwie selbstverständlich, muss aber im Umkehrschluss auch die Folgerung zulassen, dass *jede Sprache* von Kindern in ungefähr der gleichen Geschwindigkeit erlernt werden kann. Und da nicht davon auszugehen ist, dass Kinder einer Muttersprache intelligenter seien als solche anderer Muttersprachen, muss folgen, dass alle Sprachen ungefähr gleich schwer zu lernen sind.
2. Egal, welche Sprache ich lerne, ich muss irgendwann für alle Wörter, die ich in meinem aktiven Wortschatz haben möchte, eine Verknüpfung im Gehirn zwischen dem Konzept des Wortes und dem entsprechenden Wort der zu lernenden Sprache herstellen. Dabei ist es meines Erachtens völlig unerheblich, ob das Wort ähnlich, identisch oder unähnlich ist, ich *muss es mir merken*. Da es keine Sprache gibt, deren Wortschatz zu 100 % mit dem einer anderen Sprache übereinstimmt, wird es *immer* mindestens eine Ausnahme von der Regel geben, und alleine um sich diese Ausnahme zu merken, muss man sich den Rest auch merken.

   Es spielt also für den Aufwand keine Rolle, ob ich mir als neues Wort für *Katze* nun *cat*, *chat*, *kissa* oder 猫 (*neko*) merken muss. Selbst die oft kolportierten zehn Wörter für Schnee bei Inuit (oder zehn Wörter für Sand bei Beduinen) lasse ich hier nicht gelten, denn umgekehrt gibt es für das jeweils andere Phänomen (sofern die *urban Legends* überhaupt wahr sind) entsprechend weniger Begriffe.
3. Gleiches gilt für die Grammatik. Die eine Sprache kennt zwar vielleicht nur eine formale Vergangenheitsform, andere zwei, drei oder noch mehr; wieder andere kommen ohne Futur aus. Vollkommen egal: Ich muss mir merken, wie die Form(en) gebildet werden, und eine Intuition entwickeln, wann sie wie eingesetzt werden. Dabei hilft es nicht, wenn nur eine Vergangenheitsform existiert: Es können durchaus unterschiedliche Verwendungen verschiedener Phrasen vorkommen. Vielleicht nutzt die Sprache diese eine Vergangenheit mehr im Sinne eines Plusquamperfektes, und Aussagen wie *das war wohl nichts* sind in der Gegenwart zu formulieren.

   Und es gilt wieder, was oben kurz angeklungen ist: Auch wenn eine Sprache Zeiten *fast* wie das Deutsche benutzt, muss man sich mindestens die Unterschiede merken.
4. Zuletzt die Aussprache. Die muss man tatsächlich von der Pike auf lernen, durch hören und wiedergeben. Dabei behaupten auch wieder manche, dass einige Sprachen mehr Wert auf gewisse Unterschiede legen (exemplarisch kommt hier oft Chinesisch mit seinen vier Worttönen). Das ist aber, relativ gesehen, Humbug. Wenn ich mir anhöre, wie manche Menschen versuchen, Deutsch oder Englisch wiederzugeben, läuft es mir eiskalt den Rücken herunter, ab und an sind Wörter selbst mit Kontext nicht mehr unterscheidbar. Diese Menschen haben nie den gleichen Aufwand in die Aussprache gesteckt wie in andere Teile der Sprache. Das führt (für sie) zu der Ansicht, Deutsch oder Englisch sei leicht, weil leicht auszusprechen. In Wirklichkeit haben sie aber mit der Optimierung weit früher aufgehört, als sie es bei anderen Sprachen getan hätten.

   Ich verlange hier kein völlig akzentfreies Sprechen; das ist fast unmöglich. Ich verlange nur eine Aussprache, bei der der Akzent deutlich in den Hintergrund tritt und für Ungeübte von einem muttersprachlichen Akzent nicht mehr zu unterscheiden ist.

Selbstverfreilich kennt jede, die eine Sprache gelernt hat, Beispiele, die ein Fragment einer Sprache einfacher zu machen scheinen als das gleiche Fragment einer anderen Sprache. Die anderen Antworten strotzen nur so von solchen Beispielen. Nur wird aus Anekdoten wissenschaftlich gesehen kein Beweis.

Aus meiner Sicht kann man das Lernen von Sprachen mit dem Lernen von Dialekten fast 1:1 vergleichen. Niemand würde behaupten, Plattdeutsch, Bairisch, Südbadisch, Berlinisch, Kölsch oder Sächsisch wäre einfacher zu lernen als irgendein anderer dieser Gruppe. Der Aufwand für das fehlerfreie Erlernen eines Dialekts ist aus meiner Sicht identisch mit dem Aufwand, den man betreiben muss, um eine Sprache zu erlernen.

Festzuhalten bleibt aus meiner Sicht:
**Sprachen sind nicht leichter oder schwerer zu lernen als andere Sprachen. Jede zu lernende Sprache ist auf ihre spezielle Art gleich schwer (oder leicht) wie alle anderen.**

Einschränkung: Das gilt in der Hauptsache nur für Sprachen mit einem festen Sprecherkern oder sogar Muttersprachlerkern, da das Erlernen rein vom Schriftlichen sich vom Sprechen doch deutlich unterscheidet.

Comment: Sehr gute Antwort. Die anderen Antworten gehen nämlich immer davon aus, dass man eine Sprache als *Fremd*-Sprache erlernt, und da hängt es ja sehr von den Sprachen ab, die man bereits beherrscht. In solchen Vergleichen kommt immer wieder zutage, dass Chinesisch bzw. Mandarin so unglaublich schwer zu lernen wäre. Das scheint mir aber dadurch begründet zu sein, dass man dazu hauptsächlich Amerikaner und Europäer befragt hat. Ich vermute, dass es für Japaner oder Koreaner leichter ist Mandarin zu lernen als Englisch oder Deutsch.

Answer (score 1):

Vielleicht ist meine Antwort ein bisschen spät aber ich lerne Deutsch als Fremdsprache, und mir ist nichts zu einfach oder zu schwierig, aber die meisten meiner Kollegen können die Wörter, die mit dem Aufbauprinzip gebaut werden, nicht korrekt trennen.