# Überrascht sein von vs überrascht sein über

Tags: difference, preposition

Was ist der Unterschied (wenn es überhaupt einen gibt) zwischen "überrascht sein ***von*** etwas" und "überrascht sein ***über*** etwas"?

Gibt es Beispiele wenn man nur "überrascht sein von" bzw. nur "überrascht sein über" verwenden kann, und nicht die andere Weise?

Comment: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20315/sprechen-von-vs-sprechen-%C3%BCber
Dies könnte dir helfen ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ohne Kontext ist das nur ungefähr zu beantworten. Eine Möglichkeit:

Das Verb *überraschen* kann passiv konstruiert werden. Das Subjekt der korrespondierenden Aktivkonstruktion wird dann mit '*von*' (oder '*durch*
') angeschlossen.

> der Einbrecher wurde von einer Polizeistreife überrascht

= die Polizei hat ihn zufällig beobachtet und dann eingegriffen

Dieses '*überraschen*' kann '*ertappen*' bedeuten, geht aber auch in '*überrumpeln*' über und heißt dann '*einer Sache unvorbereitet ausgesetzt oder ausgeliefert sein*':

> viele Pendler wurden von den unangekündigten Streiks bei den Nahverkehrsbetrieben unangenehm überrascht

Die Überraschung kann auch positiv sein:

> als sie das Büro betrat, wurde sie von ihren Kollegen mit einem Geburtstagsständchen überrascht.

Als 'Sein-Passiv' verliert nach meinem Gefühl das '*überrascht*' den Verb-Charakter und geht in ein Adjektiv über, das in erster Linie den psychischen Effekt auf den Betroffenen bezeichnet und weniger das Ergebnis einer Aufeinanderfolge von Vorgängen. Es kommt als Adjektiv ohne

> wir waren alle überrascht

und mit präpositionaler Erweiterung mit '*über*' vor:

> wir waren überrascht über diesen phänomenalen Erfolg.

Man kann hier jedoch oft auch ein Sein-Passiv konstruieren:

> wir waren überrascht von diesem Erfolg.

Je nachdem, ob der Sprecher noch stärker die Ableitung aus dem Passiv (der Erfolg hat die Überraschung zur Folge) oder einen adjektivischen Charakter (den Überraschungseffekt beim Betroffenen) betonen will, wird er die Präposition '*von*' (Passiv) oder '*über*' (Adjektiv) bevorzugen. In der Praxis wird sich das vermischen.

Derartige Vermischungen und Gebrauchsbeschränkungen erlebt man auch mit anderen Partizipien-Adjektiven:

> sie wurde von ihm immer wieder enttäuscht
>
> sie war von ihm enttäuscht
>
> ?sie war über ihn enttäuscht
>
> sie war über ihr schlechtes Abschneiden beim Test sehr enttäuscht
>
> sie war von ihrem schlechten Abschneiden beim Test sehr enttäuscht

Oder mit 'erfreut':

> das hat ihn sehr erfreut
>
> ??er wurde von seinen Kollegen erfreut
>
> ?er war von ihnen erfreut
>
> er war über das Geschenk erfreut
>
> ??er war von dem Geschenk erfreut

'Erfreuen' scheint nicht passivierbar zu sein. Für solche und ähnliche Fälle eine regelhafte Erklärung zu finden, könnte das Problem '*von*' oder '*über*' in einem allgemeineren Rahmen lösen.

Answer (score 4):

Wenn ich der Aussage auf die Spur gehe, sehe ich spontan keine Unterschiede.
Wenn es aber hilft zur Findung:

- überrascht von jemandem
- überrascht über jemanden

da gibt es einen Unterschied. Der erste Punkt betrifft stärker den Punkt, das jemand mich überrascht, z.B. mit einem Geschenk. Der zweite betrifft eher den Aspekt, dass ich z.B. von einem Dritten etwas über jemanden erfahre, was micht dann überrascht.

Um damit dann zur Ausgansfrage zu kommen, gefühlt würde ich keinen grossen Unterschied sehen, aber einen Feinen schon, am Beispiel:

- überrascht vom schlechten Wetter: ein schneller Wetterumschwung in den Bergen würde ich nur so adressieren
- überrascht über das schlechte Wetter: "ich wusste gar nicht, dass es hier auch schlechtes Wetter gibt"

Comment: Es sollte wohl "überrascht über jemande**n**" heißen.