# Fragewort für dass?

Tags: usage

Wenn die Antwort lautet wie folgt: "Ich bin überrascht, dass du da bist.", was wäre dann das zugehörige Fragewort. Ich würde denken z.B. "warum"/"wieso"/"weshalb" ... usw., aber keine von denen klingt 100% richtig.

Z.B., in dem folgenden Beispiel, keine der Alternativen (warum, wieso, ... usw.) klingt mir 100% richtig. Ich kann jedoch an keine bessere Lösung denken.

> - Warum bist du überrascht?
> - Ich bin überrascht, dass du da bist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Überrascht sein von vs überrascht sein über](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/43508/%c3%9cberrascht-sein-von-vs-%c3%bcberrascht-sein-%c3%bcber)

Comment: Die ältere Konstruktion war der Genitiv: "Ich bin froh, dass Du da bist." - "Dessen bin ich froh." / "Des sind wir froh!" und folgerichtig: "Wes bist du froh?" Aber diese Formen sind so veraltet, dass sie heute keine Alternative mehr darstellen.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ich kann keine Duplizität erkennen. Die genannte Frage beschäftigt sich damit, wie "überraschen" angeschlossen wird. Diese Frage hingegen mit dem Fragewort zu "dass". Zwar hat der OP das gleiche Verb wie in der anderen Frage gewählt, hätte aber auch ein anderes nehmen können (z. B. verwundert), ohne den Sinn dieser Frage zu verändern.

Answer (score 6):

> Ich bin überrascht, dass du da bist.

Das Fragewort ist **worüber**, denn *überrascht sein* benötigt die Präposition *über*. Mit einem Objektsatz (dass…) kommt diese Präposition im Satz nicht vor, verwendet man stattdessen aber ein Substantiv, sieht man sie:

> Ich bin **über** dein Dasein überrascht.

Alternativ ginge auch *von* und *wovon*.

Comment: Also wenn ich richtig verstehe muss man immer "Wovon bist du überrascht?" bzw. "Worüber bist du überrascht?" fragen. (Ich bin ein bisschen davon überrascht :) Ich dachte "Warum bist du überrascht?" wäre auch möglich...)

Comment: *Warum bist du überrascht?* ist nicht falsch, fragt aber nicht direkt nach dem Objekt. *Warum/Wieso/Weshalb* fragen immer nach einem ganzen Satz. Anwortet jemand z.B. auf die Frage *Wieso haben Sie kein Brot?* mit *Der Ofen!* muss sich der Frager dazudenken, dass gemeint ist, der Ofen sei kaputt.

Comment: @Attilio Grammatikalisch gesehen ist hier nur „worüber“ bzw. „über wen oder was?“ die richtige Frage nach dem Objektsatz. Im Alltag wäre aber die Frage „warum?“ sicher auch verständlich, da wir Menschen nun mal nicht immer strikt nach der Grammatik denken.